# Make Bootstrap Modal zoom out from clicked object

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm writing custom transition for Bootstrap modal. How to make it zoom out(scale) to the center from the button you clicked, and then when you dismiss it, zoom in back to the button?

[image]

I found [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/prkLwvgk/) with zoom(scale) transition, but it scales from one place, rather then custom reference point:

```
var $modal= $('.modal');

$('.target-area').on('click', function (e) {
    $modal.css({top: e.clientY, left: e.clientX, transform: 'scale(0.1, 0.1)'});
    $modal.modal();
    $modal.css({top: '', left: '', transform: ''});
});


$('#dismissModal').click(function(){
    $modal.css({top: 0, left: 0, transform: 'scale(0.1, 0.1)', opacity:'0'});
setTimeout(function(){
        $('.modal').modal('hide')
    },750);
});

$modal.on('hidden', function () {
    $modal.css({top: '', left: '', transform: '', opacity:''});
});

....

<div class="target-area">
    Click anywhere to launch modal
</div>

<div class="modal hide">
  <div class="modal-header">
      <h3>Header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Body
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="dismissModal" class="btn">Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you "run it in fullscreen"? (I.e. make the result part as big as possible.) I think the code works correctly only if the resulting html is rendered from top left of the browser viewport (which it isn't in jsfiddle).

Comment: @ArneHugo "fullscreen" doesn't fix it. Need more reliable solution...

Comment: I just tried [the fiddle you linked](http://jsfiddle.net/prkLwvgk/) again, and now it seems to work perfectly (in Chrome and Firefox). Does it still not work for you? (jsfiddle now renders the result in an iframe, which behaves as a browser window within the browser window, with it's own `clientX` and `clientY`. Not sure if jsfiddle used iframe before or not, but if it is a new feature then that is what fixed it.) Let me know if it's still not working.

Comment: By the way, in the [fiddle you linked](http://jsfiddle.net/prkLwvgk/), the modal would zoom back toward `x: 0, y: 0` when dismissed. I made a small tweak to make it [zoom back to the same place](http://jsfiddle.net/ms5jpk7n/) it emerged from when dismissed.